# Issue with Sql Query (randomly adding value from one table to another)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table `Accounts` and `Proxies`.

I have almost 100 proxies in `Proxies` table now i want to randomly assign proxies to the `Accounts` table . I am using this query :

```
update Accounts set proxy= (select top 1 proxy from Proxies order by newid())
```

but it updates all the rows with the same proxy looking at the query in theory i believe it should randomly get a new proxy for each row .

Comment: it will update all the records, because there is no where clause

Comment: The "WHERE" clause is missing in the query.  This is the reason it updates all rows with same value

Comment: Look at my fixed answer - i have tried it on sqlfiddle now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because it is uncorelated subquery and it is computed only once.
Try to change it to:

```
update A 
set proxy= (select top 1 proxy from Proxies P WHERE P.proxy-P.proxy=A.proxy-A.proxy order by newid()) 
FROM Accounts A
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c68ce/4/1

this query is like 0=0 but correlated from optimizer POV

Comment: Worked by adding ID Col :)

Answer (score 0):

use `where` clause example

```
update Accounts set proxy= (select top 1 proxy from Proxies order by newid())
where Accounts.col =something
```

Comment: that means i am going to update each row one by one :) not good

Comment: @confusedMind  also based on condition you can do  that for that you have to use case when clause

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.proxy= t2.proxy
FROM Accounts t1
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT TOP 1 p.proxy
   FROM Proxies p
   WHERE p.proxy= t1.proxy
   ORDER BY newid()
) t2
```